# Google captcha returning an error not showing the captcha on frontend contact form

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

I am getting the google captcha error shown below using WordPress, not showing the captcha on the frontend form Gravity forms.

> The resource from
> “http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=APIKEY&hl=en”
> was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch
> (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)